# wrong tally shown on reputation page

Tags: bug

This detail of my reputation page has two errors. First the tally for "Memory (RAM)..." is wrong, should be +45. Second it's listed twice, the second time with a different, but also wrong tally. I posted only one answer there, however.

When I refresh the page it's shown correctly.

**update**
I had the same error again today.

[image]

**edit**
How it should be read. When I went to the page it listed the changes since my last visit in yellow, 4 lines: "Memory...", "What is a constant...", "Convert DS18B20..." and "Generation of ...". The last three are single events, +10 for each. The first one is the total of more than 1 event, as indicated by a right arrow, like on the line "Least expensive...".
When you click the arrow it changes to a down arrow and the details are expanded. That's when the 4 gray lines become visible. So the 3 x +10 and the +15 are the details for the top line. I count 4 events, not 2, and a total of +45, not +25.

[image]

This is how it looks when I refresh: the "+20/2 events" has become "+45/4 events". The second occurrence of the group "Memory..." has gone (as it should). This has nothing to do with rep cap (that wouldn't have shown the +10s!). I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The sum is correct, so the error is just that they are separated.

I would say that's because it highlights the reputation change from the last visit, so to me it's by design.

Comment: No, the "+20, 2 events" is the (wrong) sum of three upvotes and an accept. That should be "+45, 4 events".

Comment: @stevenvh, not to me. You received 3 separate upvotes(different answers), 1 accept, and 2 upvotes on the same answer(2 events). That page is messy to read though.

Comment: @Kortuk - I added to my question in an attempt to clarify.

Comment: @stevenvh 25+20=45 and 2+2=4 so the values are correct. The bug is with how the line items are duplicated.

Comment: @Kellenjb - ?? 45 is the correct value, but that isn't shown anywhere! That should be the first line. Same with "4 events", should be the first line! It's OK when I refresh the page. There really is a discrepancy.

Comment: @stevenvh, when I look at your reputation it all seems to line up but **many** of the upvotes are giving 0 reputation due to rep cap, it might be bugging right as that happens. Does it look okay now when you look at yesterday?

Comment: @stevenvh Can you show the screen shot after you refresh? The way I see it, you have 4 total events for "Memory (RAM)..." The system grouped the items into 2 sets of 2 with rep of 20 and 25 for each group. The problem is that when it displayed the line item details for the groups, it shows 4 lines each instead of just 2 in the first group and 2 in the second group. So either they need to fix it to not have 2 separate groups or they should fix it to not show all 4 line items in each group when it should only be 2.

Comment: @Kellenjb - that's a good interpretation. But then it should only have shown the lines it counted for the two groupings. I updated the question with another screenshot.